# Prevent duplication of CSS custom properties when using prefers-color-scheme

Tags: css, sass, themes, custom-properties

I handle theming on my web app using around 60 custom properties. Currently I have 2 themes: light and dark (original I know).

Because the dark theme can be set using the user's preference (via a class) as well as being based on their OS preference using: @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) I end up duplicating the dark theme properties. This isn't a massive issue in terms of maintenance as I use SCSS to generate the themes. But it does duplicate it in the output, which is 60 lines I could probably get rid of.

For your viewing pleassure I have removed a few of the properties:

```
:root,
.theme--light {
  --theme-style-1: #fff;
  --theme-style-2: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}    
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --theme-style-1: #444; // duplicated
        --theme-style-2: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); // duplicated
    }
}    
.theme--dark {
    --theme-style-1: #444; // duplicated
    --theme-style-2: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); // duplicated
}
```

## My question then, is there a way to prevent the duplication?

This is the SCSS that generates the themes which works perfectly apart from the duplication:

```
:root,
.theme--light{
    @each $varName, $value in $themeBase__map {
        --#{$varName}: $value;
    }
}    
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
    @each $varName, $value in $themeDark__map {
        --#{$varName}: $value;
    }
    }
}    
.theme--dark {
    @each $varName, $value in $themeDark__map {
        --#{$varName}: $value;
    }
}
```

But I have tried using @extend .theme__dark in the media query like this:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        @extend .theme--dark;
    }
}
```

Which yields this lovely error (which is kind of obvious):

[image]

Appreciate any ideas you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be **inside** a media query and `@extend` something that's **outside** of a media query. It certainly would be nice if it would simply take a copy of it instead of trying to compose the selectors. But it doesn't, so you can't.

### Solution:- Use a mixin

If you're going to be reusing a block of code **inside** and **outside** a media query, and still want to extend it, then write both a `@mixin` and an `@extend` class:

```
@mixin foo {
    // Put something here...
}

%foo {
    @include foo;
}

// usage
.foo {
    @extend %foo;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .bar {
        @include foo;
    }
}
```

*In case someone doesn't know what the `%` selector is, its just a placeholder selector, ie, it won't get compiled to CSS yet you will be able to reuse the code.*

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm trying to prevent the duplication in the compiled file. The mixin / extend method would still duplicate the styles.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles Unless Sass allows to extend an outer selector from within media, we can't get rid of duplication. There are some open issues on this feature. I hope it will get implemented soon.

Comment: Can it be done without SASS? Because I'm not using extend. I'm generating the properties into each class from a map.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles With Sass, the compiled css WILL produce duplications. This is what I think. But I will leave this to more experienced developers out there. If I find a solution, I will share it with you.